# How to show $f(x)=(e^x-1)/x, x>0$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

How does one show that $f(x)=(e^x-1)/x$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$? I plotted the curve and it looks clearly convex. However, when I tried differentiating it, I cannot show the second derivative, $$ f''(x) = \frac{x^3e^x-2x^2e^x+2xe^x-2x}{x^4},$$ remains nonnegative on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Try looking at the power series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

I think the easy way to do this is with Taylor series. Note
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^x-1}{x} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}
$$
so
$$
f''(x) = \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{k!} x^{k-3}
$$
where every term is non-negative for non-negative $x$...

Answer (score 2):

The power series has all positive coefficients, so all derivatives are positive for $x > 0$.